# ProjectEuler Q2: Haskell solution won't evaluate

Tags: haskell

I invite you to check out the following fibonacci related problem from [project Euler](https://projecteuler.net/problem=2). The question asks the users to first generate a fibonacci sequence or function capable of returning the nth fibonacci number. I used the zipWith solution to generate a lazy/infinite list of fibonacci numbers:

```
fibs = 0 : 1 : zipWith (+) fibs (tail fibs)
```

Next, the question asks to restrict the list to fibonacci numbers/values less than 4e6, and then sum the even numbers. I *thought* this would be a very simple list comprehension:

```
sum [x | x<-fibs, even x && x < (4*10^6 + 1)]
```

This expression will not finish evaluating.... I thought it would proceed until it finds the right-most number (the first fib greater than 4e6, the 34th element in the list `fibs!!34`) and then terminate the list, summing a small number of integers. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You can use `takeWhile` to stop processing the list when it no longer satisfies a predicate.

Comment: The list is monotonic increasing, but haskell doesn't know this - so it won't stop evaluating elements from it just because you go over a threshold that's tied into a predicate in a list comprehension running over it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`ghc` doesn't know when `[x | x<-fibs, even x && x < (4*10^6 + 1)]` should terminate and it will try to exhaust the infinite list `fibs`. In otherwords, it will try to exhaust an infinte list of fibonacci numbers before termating. You should look into [`takeWhile`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.1.0/docs/Data-List.html).

Comment: The direct answer is `[y | y<- takeWhile (\x -> x < 4*10^6 + 1) fibs, even y]`